# How to interlace synchronous queues

Tags: swift, queue, synchronous

I need to sequence the order in which some data is gathered (JSON) and subsequent calculations carried out. Everything works but not in the right order.

I want to go from one queue to the next and back again, synchronously.

E.g.

Queue 1-a

Queue 1-b

> Queue 2-a

>> Queue 3-a

< Queue 2-b

< Queue 1-c

The code below just works sequentially without jumping off in the right places.

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Image(systemName: "globe")
            .imageScale(.large)
            .foregroundStyle(.tint)
        Text("Queue Test")
    }
    .padding()
    .onAppear() {
        Queue1()
    }
}
}

func Queue1() {
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Queue1")
queue.sync {
    let _ = print("Queue #1-1")
}
queue.sync {
    Queue2()
    let _ = print("Queue #1-2")
}
queue.sync {
    let _ = print("Queue #1-3")
}
}

func Queue2() {
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Queue2")
queue.sync {

    let _ = print("Queue #2-1")
}
queue.sync {
    Queue3()
    let _ = print("Queue #2-2")
}
queue.sync {
    let _ = print("Queue #2-3")
}
}

func Queue3() {
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Queue3")
queue.sync {
    let _ = print("Queue #3-1")
}
}
```

Giving a debug of:

Queue #1-1

Queue #1-2

Queue #1-3

Queue #2-1

Queue #2-2

Queue #2-3

Queue #3-1

What do I need to do to effect this? Here is a flow chart of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I follow, given the list before the code which items can run in parallel or must all run in order?

Comment: Queuer 1 should jump to Queue 2 and then to Queue 3 and then back to Queue 2 and then the original Queue 1.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. The fact that you are running the tasks asynchronously, suggests you don't care why order they run in. If you do care, run them synchronously. If you don't want to block the main thread while running them, put them all on the same sequential queue in the right order.

Comment: Watch “Meet async/aeait”

Comment: Hi - have included a flow chart in the original question as my explanation was clearly not  clear enough.

Comment: The issue is clear you can solve this by adopting the new concurrency. It would take little effort.

Comment: I think this is actually an async/await issue. I will remove this question shortly as I don't think it serves any purpose by remaining posted. Very many thanks for your steers. I have consolidated the code into one block but the problem remains. Due the async nature of the JSON pull I need to implement async/await to control it. Again, very many thanks.